# How to animate the splitting/fission of an atom

Tags: animation

I am working on a personal project an need to render the nuclear fission of an atom while also rendering the individual proton and neutron of the nucleus. Any ideas on how to animate such a process? Using instancing I can easily model a single nucleus but I'm trying to figure out how to animate the later splitting into two separate nuclei. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: It can largely depend on how scientifically accurate you want to be - animating rearrangement of protons and neutrons into two atom cores, not based on actual scientific recordings of that movement, could be misleading and in a scientific publication it would be better to not show such transition. If scientific accuracy is not needed, you could constrain each particle with the other for minimum distance, arrange them into two nuclei, move them towards each-other, render the animation and play in reverse.